# Kivy VideoPlayer loading texture

Tags: python, kivy, video-player

I have this code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
kivy.require('1.10.1')


class MyVideoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        player = VideoPlayer(source='test.mp4')
        return player


MyVideoApp().run()
```

I also have a file `test.mp4` in the same directory as this file. However, when I run this code, I get this error: `[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture test.mp4`. I do not understand what this means, or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try putting the full path to the file? Same issue possibly:https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6181 Possibly missing drivers

Comment: I still get the same error, but I will check out the GitHub link. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The GitHub did not work

Comment: Hi @Pokechu48! Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: No, not yet, but if there have been new updates to Kivy that solve this issue, I have not tried them